# TypeScript ES6 Imports for jquery-xml2json Plugin

Tags: jquery, typescript, jquery-plugins, es6-modules

I may just be doing something daft but I can't seem to get this to work.

```bash
npm init
npm install jquery --save
npm install @typings/jquery --save-dev
npm install jquery-xml2json --save
```

Attempting

```bash
npm install @typings/jquery-xml2json
```

returns HTTP 404, so I create my own Typescript definition file, `jquery-xml2json.d.ts`:

```ts
interface JQueryStatic {
    xml2json(xml: any, options?: any) : any;
}
```

Now, I want to use this in `index.ts`:

```ts
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as xml2json from 'jquery-xml2json';

var xml = '<person><name>Sam</name></person>';
var result = $.xml2json(xml);
console.log(result);
```

The Typescript compiler doesn't like this at all:

```bash
index.ts(5,16): error TS2339: Property 'xml2json' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.
```

`node --version`

`7.5.0`

`npm --version`

`4.2.0`

`tsc --version`

`2.1.6`

What am I doing wrong?